# Concrete5 generrated_overrides causes errors due to malformed PHP output

Tags: php, concrete5

We're using **Concrete5** on quite some sites in production. Most of them run fine, but once in a while we see a site producing errors due to an unwanted bracket and semicolon at the end of the config file.

The file:

```
/application/generrated_overrides/concrete.php
```

is the one causing these failures.

We've investigated the **Config/FileSaver** and **Config/Renderer** but there's no obvious reason for this to fail.

Comment: Can you show the broken content of this file?

Comment: By default it looks like: https://gist.github.com/sjorssnoeren/95e3e9ee34b278b556dfb6870a8e6954 - When failed it will add `];` to the end, which breaks the code since the `];` is already included.